# How can I add this main js to the template tags without it throwing a tag error?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, django-rest-framework, jinja2

I am building a project with Django and react.

I need to add my main.js to these script tags in my index.html file but it throws an error saying tag start not closed.

I am using PyCharm as my IDE.

```html
 <script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"></script>
```

Comment: Can you share your html code. static tags need not to be closed. There must be some other tags which are open and not closed

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Lead Manager</title>
</head>

Comment: <body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  {% load static %}
  <script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Sorry I had to add it in these separate comments because I cannot edit my question for some reason :/

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way you are not closing the quote at right position

```html
 <script src="{% static %}frontend/main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

By reviewing your code, Here what i understand.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootswatch.com/4/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css">
 <title>Lead Manager</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="app">
 </div> 
 {% load staticfiles %} 
 <script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}">
 </script>
 <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </script> 
 <script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/…" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </script>
 <script src="stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </script> 
 </body> 
 </html>
```

Please use `{% load staticfiles %}` instead of `{% load static %}`

Also check if you have `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` is in your INSTALLED APPS

Comment: That doesn't make a difference, just static is fine.